# Ubuntu on tablet

Tags: windows

I just purchased a new tablet that came with Windows 10. I want to replace the OS with Ubuntu. Problem: the HD is only 30 gb. How much space will Ubuntu take up? Windows uses 9 gb.

Answer (score 0):

My root partition (everything except the home folder) is about 5gb.  XUbuntu 13.10 (32-bit) because I haven't been updating this machine very religiously.

30gb is more than enough for the OS and personal files....as long as you aren't trying to store anything massive, you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

30GB will be plenty for Ubuntu.  If you really want to get more space, you can always upgrade to a new disk.  If you do get a new disk, buy an SSD for maximum performance.  Ubuntu can install in as little as 4GB if you do things right.